# how pass api get data in vue js router pass another page

Tags: vue.js

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/filter-trip?fromlocation='+this.form.from_place+'&tolocation='+this.form.to_place+'&assign_date='+DatabaseFormat+'',auth)
                .then(response => {
                    this.FilterTripData = response.data
                   console.log(this.FilterTripData)
                   this.$router.push({ path : '/search-bus', params: {
                           items: this.FilterTripData
                       }});
                  })
                .catch(error => {console.log(error)});
    }
```

> How Pass Api get data with Router Push and access those data another page

Answer (score 1):

```
this.$router.push({ path : '/search-bus', params: {
                       items: this.FilterTripData
                   }});
```

This is correct already. To access it in another page.

```
this.$router.currentRoute.params.items
```

Comment: How access items in search-bus page

Comment: this.$router.currentRoute.params.items

Comment: i wants to index page to search-bus page and data display in search-bus page 

how define currentRoute?

Comment: ` {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Index',
      component: Index,
      props: true
    },
    {
      path: '/search-bus',
      name: 'SearchBus',
      component: SearchBus,
      props: true,
    } `